# I received the error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis for this statement on SQL Workshop in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, sql-update, oracle-apex

Here is the code I was attempting to enter into Oracle:

```
UPDATE TRANSACTIONS
   SET INITIALPRICE = (((SELECT SALESPRICE 
                           FROM PRODUCT 
                          WHERE PRODUCTID = '104') * 2) + 
                       SELECT SALESPRICE 
                         FROM PRODUCT 
                       WHERE PRODUCTID = '105'),
       SALESTAX = (INITIALPRICE * 
                   SELECT SALESTAXRATE 
                     FROM STORE 
                    WHERE STOREID = '101'),
       TOTALPRICE = INITIALPRICE + SALESTAX
 WHERE TRANSACTIONID = '101'
```

I was attempting to update the existing record by inserting new values in the attribute. Please tell me where I may have been missing the parenthesis in the statement. Keep in mind that I used select statements to look up values for the different values in the product and store tables.

Answer (score 0):

Every select statement on the left side of the "=" sign needs to be enclosed in brackets. The one below is not:

```
                       SELECT SALESPRICE 
                         FROM PRODUCT 
                       WHERE PRODUCTID = '105'),
```

So most probably this should work:

```
UPDATE TRANSACTIONS
   SET INITIALPRICE = (((SELECT SALESPRICE 
                           FROM PRODUCT 
                          WHERE PRODUCTID = '104') * 2) + 
                       (SELECT SALESPRICE 
                         FROM PRODUCT 
                       WHERE PRODUCTID = '105')),
       SALESTAX = (INITIALPRICE * 
                   SELECT SALESTAXRATE 
                     FROM STORE 
                    WHERE STOREID = '101'),
       TOTALPRICE = INITIALPRICE + SALESTAX
 WHERE TRANSACTIONID = '101'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the error still exists. I have no idea what exactly was wrong with that as I did everything else correctly.

Comment: That is interesting. Where exactly are you getting this error. Is this in the SQL Workshop of apex or is this an application process in an apex application ? Please provide more details (preferably by updating your question with as much info as possible). The word "exactly" is pretty important... the more info you provide the easier it is for anyone reading this question to give an answer.